# Test for aggregation of binary events/successes (binomial/glm??)

Tags: poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution, binary-data

this has been vexing me for a while and I can't seem to solidify an answer beyond vague thoughts about Poisson distributions. I think this is a simple problem and I'm missing something obvious. Any thoughts appreciated, particularly with R snippets :)

Chris

Experiment: 2 replicate assays from each of 50 tissues. In the 100 samples, call a binary (0,1) event (without using tissue of origin; I'll call 1 outcomes "successes", per Bernoulli trial convention). Then score tissues for concordance (2 if both replicates are successful; 1 if only one; 0 otherwise). If the assay is working, we expect non-random numbers of concordance = 2 for tissues (i.e. the effect should replicate), given the total number of successes S.

How can I test that the distribution of (0,1,2) on *tissues*- or perhaps the proportions of (1,2) *tissues* - deviates from expectation?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a classic use case for the good old Pearson $\chi^2$ test. There's a short R tutorial [here](http://www.r-tutor.com/elementary-statistics/goodness-fit/multinomial-goodness-fit).

Basically, you have data points in one of three categories (i.e. 0, 1, or 2). You have an expected distribution of frequencies over those categories; the $\chi^2$ test is explicitly intended to check whether the observed frequencies match your expectation. In this case you'd have:
$$
\frac{o_0+e_0}{e_0}+\frac{o_1+e_1}{e_1}+\frac{o_2+e_2}{e_2}\sim\chi^2_2
$$

where, e.g. "$o_0$" is the observed number of "0" tissues and $e_0$ is the number you expect.

Also -- the outcome (0, 1, and 2) in this case is binomial, not Poisson.

Comment: Your answer ignores the pairing of the observations, and therefore hemorrhages power.

Comment: Not at all (I think). I'm treating each tissue sample as the unit of analysis, rather than each assay. Your answer addresses the correlation between replications, mine  addresses the number of successful replications. I interpreted the OP as asking about the latter.

Comment: And in doing so you are not accounting for the dependency of observations within tissue types; and Pearson's $\chi^{2}$ does not address the ordering of counts that your treatment of the data provides. Again: this analysis would hemorrhage power on these kind of data.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how the dependency matters here, unless it means that $Pr(X=2)\neq Pr(X=1)^2$ (and based on the question it doesn't seem like that's the case).

Comment: 50 tissues. Tissue #1 has two measurements. If tissue #1 is different from tissue #2, then the within-tissue variance is different than between tissue variance. Pearson's test ignores this information.

Comment: Right. I think we have two different models. Your model is $\{X_i\}_1^{100}$ where $X_i\sim\operatorname{Bernoulli}{(p)}$ with 50 clusters (or pairs or whatever). My model is $\{X_i\}_1^{50}$ where $X_i\sim\operatorname{binomial}{(2,p)}$.

Comment: $\sigma^{2} = np(1-p)$, so your model assumes $p$ is constant (i.e. if different tissues have the same success probabilities).

Comment: Sure, but I don't see any reason in the question not to assume iid observations here. That's also not the same thing as talking about intra-cluster correlation. I guess we can wait for the OP to weigh in.

Comment: Hi all - OP here. Thanks for the discussion. 

I had finally groped my way towards the Pearson's formulation too. Alexis has a point, however, that each tissue has a different overall concordance rate. I've calculated the Jaccard distance between pairs of samples and in each tissue it is different (likely reflecting sample, rather than assay, quality).

I think the assumption of iid observations hold - each sample is a biological replicate prepared separately rather than a true paired technical replicate.

Comment: To clarify the model comparison comment from ssdecontrol, I am trying to reject Alexis' Bernoulli model - my alternative is that there *should* be concordance between tissue replicates, even though I didn't use that information in the assay procedure. So the null should be the Bernoulli model, right? I hadn't considered MacNamara's test for that, but it's a great idea.

Comment: This answer looks like it might work, but it needs considerable cleaning up: the $\chi^2$ formula is erroneous; something needs to be said about the degrees of freedom to use; and some indication of how to estimate $p$ is needed, too. It's likely that with 50 tissues the $\chi^2$ distribution will not be a good approximation to the true distribution of this test statistic, either.

Answer (score 4):

**An appropriate null hypothesis is that all $n=50$ tissues are equivalent** (at least from the point of view of the assays).  Therefore we may view the data as if $2n$ assay values were assigned completely at random to the $n$ cases, with two per case.

The data can be summarized concordance score (the number of successes per case): let $n_i$ be the number of cases with score $i$, $i=0,1,2$.  The total number of successful assays therefore is $s = n_1+2n_2$ and the total number of unsuccessful assays must be $u = 2n - s.$

**I will interpret "expectation" as referring to the entire distribution of scores.**  That is, for given values of $s$ and $n$, what is the distribution of the vector $(n_0,n_1,n_2)$ when $s$ successes are scattered randomly throughout the $2n$ results?  Because the foregoing relations imply $n_0 = n - s + n_2$ and $n_1 = s - 2n_2$, it suffices to find the distribution of $n_2$.  That is, *how many concordance scores of $2$ would be produced under the null hypothesis of no difference among tissues*?

**The answer can be found recursively.**  Writing $d(n,s,n_2)$ for the probability that the concordance score will equal $2$ and considering the three possible results for the last case (that is, two successes, one success, or no success) gives

$$d(n,s,n_2) = \frac{1}{2n(2n-1)}\left(s(s-1)d(n-1,s-2,n_2-1) + 2 s u d(n-1, s-1,n_2) + u(u-1) d(n-1, s, n_2)\right).$$

This formula relates the distributions of $n_2$ for $n$ cases to those for the first $n-1$ cases.  The fractions $s(s-1)/(2n(2n-1))$, $2 s u / (2n(2n-1))$, and $u(u-1)/(2n(2n-1))$ are the chances that the last case has $2$, $1$, or $0$ successes, respectively.  The value of $s$ accordingly goes down by the quantity $2$, $1$, or $0$.  The value of $n_2$ is decreased by $1$ only when two successes are observed.

The solution is uniquely determined by the initial conditions $d(n, 0, 0) = 1$ for $n\ge 0$ and otherwise $d(n,s,n_2)=0$ whenever $n=0$ or either of $s$ or $n_2$ is negative.

A closed form for the solution may be difficult to obtain, but computing it for small to medium sizes of $n$ is straightforward and fast (by looping over $n$).  As an example, here are plots of the probability mass functions of $n_2$ for $10, 20, \ldots, 90$ successes when $n=50$ (as in the question).

[image: Figure]

The plots at the left correspond to the smaller numbers of successes.

**With this information exact tests of the null hypothesis can be performed in standard ways.**  For instance, suppose that $s=63$ of the replicates were successes with $n=50$ but only $n_2=16$ of the $50$ cases had a concordance core of $2$. To conduct a symmetric two-tailed test at a level of $\alpha=0.05$, say, check whether $D(n,s,n_2)=\sum_{c\le n_2} d(n,s,c) \lt \alpha/2$ or $1-D(n,s,n_2-1)=\sum_{c\ge n_2} d(n,s,c) \gt 1-\alpha/2$.  In this case the first sum equals $0.0222\ldots$.  This is less than $0.05/2$, demonstrating significant evidence against the null hypothesis: concordance of successes is *rarer* than expected by chance alone.  Similar calculations show that for $n=50$ and $s=63$, any value of $n_2$ between $17$ and $22$ inclusive is consistent with the null hypothesis at the $\alpha=0.05$ level.

As a further example, suppose $n=50$, $s=40$, and $n_2=5$.  (From this we deduced earlier that $n_0=n-s+n_2=15$ and $n_1=s-2n_2=30$.)  The cumulative probability is $D(50,40,5)=0.0782\ldots$.  Considered as a two-tailed test, this results in a p-value of $2\times 0.0782 = 0.156$, which few people would consider strong evidence against the null.

---

**To illustrate the theory** here is an `R` function that returns the distribution $d(n,s,n_2)$ for a given value of $n$.  It is stored in an array with $s=0,1,\ldots,2n$ indexing the rows and $n_2=0,1,\ldots,n$ indexing the columns.  (The variable `c` represents $n_2$ in this code.)

```r
f <- function(n) {
  shift <- function(x, i, j) {               # Shift x by i>=0 rows and j>=0 columns
    m <- dim(x)[1]; n <- dim(x)[2]
    y <- rbind(matrix(0, nrow=i, ncol=n), x)
    y <- cbind(matrix(0, nrow=m+i, ncol=j), y)
    y <- y[1:m, 1:n]
    dimnames(y) <- dimnames(x)
    return (y[1:m, 1:n])
  }
  s <- (-2):(2*n) # include a border of negative values of s
  c <- (-1):n     # include a border of negative values of c
  d <- zero <- matrix(0, nrow=length(s), ncol=length(c), dimnames=list(s=s, c=c))
  d["0","0"] <- 1 # Initial conditions
  for (i in 1:n) {# Apply the recursion
    u <- 2 * i - s
    t1 <- s * (s-1) * shift(d, 2, 1)
    t2 <- 2 * s * u * shift(d, 1, 0)
    t3 <- u * (u-1) * d
    d <- (t1 + t2 + t3) / (2*i * (2*i-1))
  }
  return (d[3:length(s), 2:length(c)]) # Strip the borders for negative s and c
}
```

**As an example of its use,** here is the code that produced the figure.  (It also makes an image plot of the entire distribution.)  Of interest is the post-processing of the distribution matrix `x`; notice in particular that its indexes begin at $0$ rather than $1$.

The time to compute this distribution was only $0.02$ seconds, but do not be deceived by that speed: because the algorithm scales as $n^3$, it will be practicable only for $n$ up to a thousand or so.  For instance, multiplying $n$ by $4$ will increase the time by a factor of $4^3\approx 60$: the calculation now takes $2$ seconds.  Another multiple of $4$ to $n=800$ will take about two minutes.  However, unless the observed value of $s$ is extreme, it is clear that Normal approximations will handle large values of $n$ accurately.

```r
n <- 50
system.time(x <- f(n))
s <- matrix(rep(0:(2*n), n+1), ncol=1+n)
n.2 <- t(matrix(rep(0:n, 2*n+1), ncol=2*n+1))
n.1 <- s - 2*n.2
n.0 <- n - s + n.2
good <- n.2 >= 0 & n.1 >= 0 & n.0 >= 0
x[!good] <- NA
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
image(0:(2*n), 0:n, t(apply(x, 1, rev)), asp=1/2, col=rev(topo.colors(100)),
      xlab="s", ylab="n2")

plot.strip <- function(dist, ...) {
  i <- (1:length(dist))[!is.na(dist)]
  lines(i, dist[i], ...)
  points(i, dist[i], ...)
}
successes <- floor(2*n/100 * c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90))
col <- hsv(successes/(2*n), .8, .9)
plot(c(0,n), c(0,max(x[successes+1,], na.rm=TRUE)), type="n",
     xlab="Number with score=2", ylab="Probability",
     main=paste("Distribution of Score=2 in", n, "Cases")) 
for (i in 1:length(successes)) {
  plot.strip(x[successes[i]+1,], col=col[i], cex=1/2)
}
```

Comment: If I were to use this test in a publication, is there a proper way to cite the method? Or would it have to be written out?

Comment: @geoscience123 Press the "Cite" button just below the post for the citation text.

Comment: Thank you. I guess I was wondering if this is a commonly employed method for this type of question, or if it is present in any statistical literature.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can jigger with your data structure a little bit like this:

You say that each assay is produced twice on each tissue type. If both samples receive precisely the same assay, then it should not matter to you to arbitrarily call, say, one assay on the tissue "group A" and the *other* assay on the same tissue "group B".

So, if you code your outcome/success=1, and no outcome/failure = 0, your data could be thought of as looking like:

```
Tissue  Outcome A  Outcome B

     1       0         0
     2       1         1
     3       1         1
     .       .         .
     .       .         .
     .       .         .
    49       0         1
    50       0         0
```

These look like *paired* data (because one observation of success/no success in a tissue is *paired* with a second observation of success/no success *in the same tissue type*), and when someone says "I wanna examine the correlation between paired data with binomial outcomes" I head straight over to [McNemar's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McNemar%27s_test). This require rejiggering your data, because what you are analyzing are *pairs*, and there are four kinds of pairs, and you wanna set up the counts of each (**totally** made up numbers, yo):

```
   Group A    Group B  Kind of Pair  Count of Pairs
no success  no success   concordant        15
   success  no success   discordant        11
no success     success   discordant        19
   success     success   concordant        5
```

McNemar's test is a $\chi^{2}$ equivalent to the sign test. The test statistic only examines *discordant pairs*. Let's call the count of Group A successful, but Group B not successful $r$, and then let's call the count of Group A not successful, but Group B successful $s$ (which discordant pair you call which is arbitrary). The test statistic (which is including a [Yates continuity correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yates%27s_correction_for_continuity) in that "$-1$" business) is:

$$\chi^{2}_{\text{df=1}} = \frac{\left(\left|r-s\right|-1\right)^{2}}{r+s}$$

$$\chi^{2}_{\text{df=1}} = \frac{\left(\left|11-19\right|-1\right)^{2}}{11+19} = \frac{49}{30} = 1.6\bar{3}$$

These made up data give a $p$-value of about 0.20, so unless you are being **outrageously libertine** with your Type I error preferences, you would not reject the null hypothesis. As it so happens, the null hypothesis you are testing is that there is no association between group membership and probability of success.

R can perform McNemar's test using the, ahem, **mcnemar.test()** function

Comment: This frames the situation reasonably well, but I don't understand where the "groups" come in. All I can find in the question itself is a reference to $50$ *tissues* and the question seems to be asking about the distribution of concordance scores. It gives us little to go on concerning what the "expectation" of that distribution would be, but it might be fair to interpret the ultimate phrase in terms of a permutation test of outcomes A and B. Would your "groups" perhaps be synonymous with "outcomes"? If so, the data might not permit identification of the groups if only the scores are known.

Comment: @whuber Yes. I am making the assumption that the scores are divided into groups (say, first observation/second observation), based on the concern the OP had for concordance/discordance. What do you think? Tenable? If they are not, then I would probably go some mixed effect estimate accounting for within-tissues clustering.